# How do I share data between EC2 instances on AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to use AWS as a back-end of my mobile application and I have created an EC2 instance (root device type is EBS, php and MySQL installed) and it works ok.

I would like to use a load balance and I was wondering how I can share the database between the EC2 instances.

If I can not share database with an EC2 instance has an EBS volume then how do I configure the structure so that I can have multiple EC2 instances with one shared data center that are running on a load balancer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share data on EC2 instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117630/how-do-i-share-data-on-ec2-instances)

Comment: Run your database (MySQL) in either AWS RDS or on a separate EC2 instance not behind the load balancer. Then configure the application servers use that database.